# Why is Express res.json() holding up Google Sheets API for +30 seconds

Tags: node.js, express, google-sheets, google-cloud-functions, slack-api

I am building an app that looks up a word definition in a Google sheet from a [Slack slash command](https://api.slack.com/interactivity/slash-commands). The app is hosted in Google Cloud Functions and written in Node.js.

To make the 3000ms time limit on slack commands, the app

1. posts an immediate `200 OK` response, then
2. do the lookup in Sheets, and finally,
3. returns the full reply via Slack's `request_url` as defined in the [Slack documentation](https://api.slack.com/interactivity/slash-commands#responding_to_commands).

So far, so good. But here's the kicker:

When I call `res.json()` in my main function `glossary`, Slack get's an initial reply, *but* the `sendMessageToSlackResponseURL()` isn't called for another 10-40 seconds. I eventually get the reply in Slack as expected, albeit painfully slow.

I have narrowed it down (by an embarrassing amount of `console.log()` calls) to the line:

`const reply = (await sheets.spreadsheets.values.get(request)).data.values;`

This command takes 2-3 seconds to run if `res.json()` is *not* called prior - barely making the Slack time limit. But if `res.json()` *is* called prior. This command takes up to 40 seconds.

How is the Google Sheets API call affected by a prior `res.json()` call? What am I missing?

```
// Simplified code pasted below:

exports.glossary = async (req, res) => {

    // Give immediate response to prevent 3000ms Slack timeout.
    res.json(initSlackResponse(req.body.text)); //Commenting out this line speeds up the app

    // Get glossary result from Google Sheet
    let response = await getGlossaryResults(query);

    // Return late response
    await sendMessageToSlackResponseURL(req.body.response_url, response);

    return Promise.resolve();
};

const getGlossaryResults = async (query) => {

    const content = await readFile(CREDENTIALS_PATH);
    let oAuth2Client = await authorize(JSON.parse(content));
    const request = {
        spreadsheetId: spreadsheetId,
        range: range,
        auth: oAuth2Client
    };
    //The following command takes 10-40 seconds to run if res.json(initSlackResponse(query)); has been called. 
    //If res.json() is *not* called, the command takes 2-3 seconds.
    const reply = (await sheets.spreadsheets.values.get(request)).data.values;

    // *Generate the results here
    return results;
};

function sendMessageToSlackResponseURL(responseURL, JSONmessage) {

    let postOptions = {
        uri: responseURL,
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-type': 'application/json'
        },
        json: JSONmessage
    };

    request(postOptions, (error) => {
        if (error){
            console.error(error);
        }
    });
    return Promise.resolve();
}

const initSlackResponse = (query) => {
    return {
        // *Build simple json object here
    };
};
```

Comment: Can I ask you about `res.json(initSlackResponse(req.body.text))` and `res` of `res.json(initSlackResponse(req.body.text))`?

Comment: Yeah, sure!

`res.json(...)` is the response object that replies to Slack via [Google Cloud Functions http Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http). When running this command, I receive the reply generated in `initSlackResponse` in Slack after a few milliseconds as expected.

When I call my function `glossary` from Slack, `req` and `res` are passed along. `req` has the request from Slack. `res` comes with a few functions for replying back to the origin. https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http

Not sure if that answers your question?

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand about `res.json(...)`. I apologize for my poor understanding. By the way, although I'm not sure whether this is related to the reason of the issue, for example, as a test situation, when the order of `res.json(initSlackResponse(req.body.text));` and `let response = await getGlossaryResults(query);` is swapped to `let response = await getGlossaryResults(query);` and `res.json(initSlackResponse(req.body.text));`, what result will you get?

Comment: Thanks a million for helping to investigate! The swap returns the exact same behavior and result...

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `the exact same behavior and result`, it seems that `let response = await getGlossaryResults(query);` doesn't affect to `res.json(initSlackResponse(req.body.text));`, and also, `let response = await getGlossaryResults(query);` is not affected from `res.json(initSlackResponse(req.body.text));`. So I would like to understand `res.json(initSlackResponse(req.body.text));`. But I cannot understand about it. I apologize for my poor skill. When I could correctly understand about it and find the reason of the issue, I would like to tell you.

Comment: *CORRECTION TO THE ABOVE.* After a bit more testing, it seems that flipping the order fixes the delay. Meaning running `res.json()` then `await sheets.spreadsheets.values.get(request))` is slow, (~20 sec) while running `await sheets.spreadsheets.values.get(request)` then `res.json()` is fast. (~2 sec). Not sure what to make of this.

Comment: Thank you for replying and additional information. Unfortunately, although I cannot still understand `res.json(initSlackResponse(req.body.text));`, will your result be affected with the order of `let response = await getGlossaryResults(query);` and `res.json(...)`?